# Javascript: Closing opened window from within

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to close opened window from within?

For example i have opened window with some external domain, then it performs some auth and redirect back to my webpage.

Is it possible to close windows after that?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to close the window that you're currently in, you can use the following code:

```
self.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you open the window, assign it to some variable:

```
authWindow = window.open("");
```

Then when you're done with it, you can close it:

```
authWindow.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var popupWindow = window.open(.....);
popupWindow.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var w = window.open(/*arguments*/);
```

Now `w` is DOMWindow object.

```
w.opener === window; //true
w.close();
```

After that value of the `opener` property is `null`

```
w.opener === null; //true
```

I hope this helps.